# Google oauth2 get accessToken using javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

I am implementing google login using javascript and oAuth2. I get to the point where I show 'accept permissions' window, then user clicks 'accept' and it goes back to my redirect_uri link. Here I have no idea how to grab accessToken which comes with the response.. Can someone show a small javascript example how to grab that token, so I could use it later? Thanks

Comment: you must exchange the code you receive to get an accesstoken.  Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 2):

The easy solution is to use a javascript oauth 2.0 library like this:
https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso